# Limit posts when visited with mobile devices

Tags: php, mobile

I found this on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135388/wordpress-change-the-limit-of-the-number-of-posts-just-for-mobile

I implemented the answer, yet it didn't work. I'm working with the AccessPress Mag template, post count on larger screens is set to unlimited.

This is the code I tried:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','change_limit_mobile');

function change_limit_mobile($query){

    $new_limit = 10;

    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
    $berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
    $ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

    if (( $iphone || $android || $ipad || $ipod || $berry ) && $query->is_main_query()){
        set_query_var('posts_per_page',$new_limit);
    }
}
```

I tried adding it to functions.php and the index.php pages, but no luck.

Has anything changed since the latest update, or do I miss something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original answer**: You could instead try using MobileESP by downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahand/mobileesp/master/PHP/mdetect.php to your theme directory and then:

```
function change_limit_mobile( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/mdetect.php';
        $mdetect = new uagent_info;
        if ( $mdetect->DetectMobileLong() ) {
            set_query_var( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**: the simplest thing is to use `wp_is_mobile()` - probably good enough!

**Theme-specific update**: In the case of the theme AccessPress Mag you're using, then it uses its own options to control the number of posts in the special home-page block loops. One way to override these is to define your own version of the pluggable theme framework options function in "functions.php":

```
function of_get_option( $name, $default = false ) {

    $option_name = '';

    // Gets option name as defined in the theme
    if ( function_exists( 'optionsframework_option_name' ) ) {
        $option_name = optionsframework_option_name();
    }

    // Fallback option name
    if ( '' == $option_name ) {
        $option_name = get_option( 'stylesheet' );
        $option_name = preg_replace( "/\W/", "_", strtolower( $option_name ) );
    }

    // Get option settings from database
    $options = get_option( $option_name );

    // Return specific option
    if ( isset( $options[$name] ) ) {
        /******* Addition Begin *******/
        // NOTE: Can add other options here...
        if ( 'posts_for_block1' === $name ) {
            return change_limit_mobile( $options[$name] );
        }
        /******* Addition End *******/
        return $options[$name];
    }

    return $default;
}
```

where `change_limit_mobile()` is now:

```
function change_limit_mobile( $value ) {
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
        $value = 10;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding mdetect.php to my theme's directory and then adding your code to functions.php. That resulted in an error, website didn't load anymore.

Comment: Ok maybe your include path isn't set, so an explicit path with `get_stylesheet_directory()` might be better - will update answer...

Comment: I'm afraid I keep getting a 500 error. I do use your code in the functions.php page right, position doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes "functions.php" is the right file, and position (now, with the absolute path) shouldn't matter. If you go into admin > Appearance > Editor, does "mdetect.php" appear in the list of templates on the right hand side, and if so if you click it does it load in the textbox?

Comment: Yes it does, please see this link (image): http://imgur.com/YIZ5yB4

Comment: Ok, the only thing I can suggest is to turn on debugging by editing your "wp-config.php" and changing the `WP_DEBUG` define to `true` and then seeing what error occurs...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31232/discussion-between-michael-and-bonger).

Comment: Updated with theme-specific stuff...

Comment: Do I copy both code snippets in the functions.php page?

Comment: Yes - back in chat now.